# How to solve a + 2^a = 6?

Tags: exponential-function

I tried solving the above equation, but was unable to solve it.

How do you basically isolate the exponent and retain the other variable in the same degree.

How to solve a + 2^a = 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *no* analytical method to solve this transcendental equation, because it mixes a variable and an exponential. But you can observe that the $LHS$ is a monotonous function (as it is the sum of two growing functions), and there is at most one solution.

By inspection, $2+2^2=6$ and you are done.

---

The equation was "arranged" to have an integer solution. Had it not been, you would have had to resort to a numerical method. By trying a few "random" values,

$$0+2^0<6$$ and $$3+2^3>6$$ shows you that the solution lies in $(0,3)$, and you can try intermediate values to get a tighter bracketing. Specific methods exist to reduce the bracketing as fast as possible.

Answer (score 4):

The function $f(x)=x+2^x$ is increasing as $f'(x)=1+\ln{(2)} 2^x \gt 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. So, the only solution to the equation given in the set $\mathbb{R}$ is $a=2$.

Comment: Solution is correct, but I think he is asking how to solve the equation, without doing guess and check.

Comment: I don't think one could do this without the Newton-Raphson method for example.